# Will There Be Difference for Git Merge Feature Branch to Master Compare to Master to Feature

Tags: git, merge, git-flow

I intended to merge new features (in Feature branch) into Master branch. I went ahead to merge Feature into Master. However, I found a line was missing from Master. However, if I merged Master into Feature and then Feature back into Master, the line is retained in Master. My question is, is there a difference of merging Feature into Master and Master into Feature? Thanks

Additional information, hot fixes were added to Master after Feature was checked out from Master. Therefore, it is merging Feature into "Master-2".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before performing any merge it's good to **fetch** for changes and perform **pulls** in case some of the branches you want to use had some changes in origin that you don't have in local.

When you perform a git merge from **Feature Branch** to **Master** you are getting all the changes from Feature Branch to Master.

So, the result would be:

- **Feature Branch** doesn't change.
- **Master** gets all the changes from Feature Branch.

When you perform a git merge from **Master** to **Feature Branch** you are getting all the changes from Master branch to the Feature Branch (you are catching up all the changes from master to that branch to set it up to date).

So, the result would be:

- **Master** doesn't change.
- **Feature branch** gets all the changes from Master.

So, yes, suposing you want to set the new functionality in master you should still perform another merge from the Feature Branch that has all the changes to Master in that second case or your master branch will not get updated.

The feature branches should be about little features, in case you are working on a feature branch that doesn't get merged after a day it's also good to perform a fetch request from master (well, it should be develop in case you followed gitflow) to that branch to keep it up to date and prevent from possible merge conflicts in the future.

But in any case, I recommend you to follow [gitflow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html). You should work with develop and feature branches and master should only be updated when a release is done. And, unless you work alone, the merges **to** develop and **to** master should be in the form of a pull request/merge request so that some of your colleagues can check your code.