# What is the difference between `git checkout master && git merge feature-branch` and `git checkout feature-branch && git merge master`?

Tags: git

What is the difference between `git checkout master && git merge feature-branch` and `git checkout feature-branch && git merge master`?

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60640907/23299948), but I'm still confused. I could've tried asking follow-up questions in the comment section, but I'm not allowed to post comments till I get 50 rep so I'll ask it in a new question

Suppose we execute `git checkout master && git merge feature-branch`

```
* Merge commit
|\
| * First feature commit
* | Third master commit
|/
* Second master commit
* First master commit
```

Here's what Jeprubio (the responder) had to say:

> Before performing any merge it's good to fetch for changes and perform pulls in case some of the branches you want to use had some changes in origin that you don't have in local.
>
> When you perform a git merge from Feature Branch to Master you are getting all the changes from Feature Branch to Master.
>
> So, the result would be:
>
> **Feature Branch doesn't change.**
>
> Master gets all the changes from Feature Branch.

However, we know for certain that a merge commit has two parents: the latest commit of the branch we merge into and the latest commit of the merged branch

> You can also specify a number after the ^ to identify which parent you want; for example, d921970^2 means “the second parent of d921970.” This syntax is useful only for merge commits, which have more than one parent — **the first parent of a merge commit is from the branch you were on when you merged (frequently master), while the second parent of a merge commit is from the branch that was merged (say, topic)**
>
> *Pro Git, p. 223*

If the merge commit

a) contains changes from both `master` and `feature`

b) belongs to both branches

then I don't see how `git checkout master && git merge feature-branch` is different from `git checkout feature-branch && git merge master`. It seems in both cases the branches *do* change: `feature` now has `master`'s changes, and `master` now has `feature`'s changes

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merge commit does contain parents from both branches, but it doesn't *belong* to both branches - it only belongs to the destination branch:

- If you run `git checkout feature-branch && git merge master`, then the new HEAD on `feature-branch` will contain everything from both branches, but `master` will be unchanged. This is especially useful if `feature-branch` includes some incomplete work; you can keep working on `feature-branch` and your merge will not introduce possibly-risky changes to `master`.
- Similarly, if you run `git checkout master && git merge feature-branch`, then `master` will contain everything from both branches, but `feature-branch` will be unchanged.